# Show a label content in double quotes

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to show myLabel in double quotes like "MyTestString".Iam using following content string format.Please correct me ,its not showing in quotes.

```
<Label ContentStringFormat="\&quot;{0}\&quot;"  Content="{Binding MyLabel}"     
              Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="20"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the slashes:

```
<Label ContentStringFormat="&quot;{0}&quot;"  Content="{Binding MyLabel}"     
              Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="20"/>
```

But why don't you add your quotes when you get `MyLabel` from your model?

```
private string myLabel;
public string MyLabel
{
    get
    {
        return "\"" + this.myLabel + "\"";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Even with slashes it shows double quotes.

Comment: Thanks ,yes it works both ways.I realized that some globally set style was overriding Label default style so It was not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You shoule use

```
<TextBlock Text='You shouldn&apos;t choose &quot;Copy if New&quot;:'/>
```